# How To Disable Button Close On Browser For Web Application?

Tags: c#, javascript, vb.net

I have Application Web based ASP.Net Framework 1.0, **for security i want Button Close (X) in browser(ie,firefox,opera etc.) is disable** and reason anything make browser exit, user only can exit browser with my menu logoff.

Please help me

Thanks in Advance

Regards,
Yusan Susandi.

Comment: By the way: do you want to prevent the user from pulling off the AC plug, too?

Comment: Why the downvote? Perfectly reasonable question, and clear enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't do this, sorry. You'll have to implement a server-side timeout mechanism, etc. You can make it a fairly short timeout and use an ajax request behind-the-scenes to keep the session alive, but you cannot prevent the browser from closing.

And really, you don't want to rely on doing so anyway, because browsers can *crash* rather than close, computers can get unplugged rather than shut down properly, etc., all without your server being notified. So you have to handle the fact that people can abruptly disappear *anyway*.

For the normal use case, you can *encourage* your users to use the Logout link instead using JavaScript:

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (loggedIn) {
        return "Please cancel and use the Logout link instead";
    }
};
</script>
```

...which will nag them on most (but not all) browsers, but you can't *make* them do it.

Comment: even if you could do this it would be a very bad idea, you would be essentially leaving the 'security' of your website up to the implementation of the browser

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, and see also my second paragraph -- not even just up to the implementation of the browser, but people can trip over power cords, and of course browsers can *crash* as well as shut down nicely. :-)

Comment: If i redirect to other page this notification always true/display, i not have master page for this my web application, so have other way for this? Please help me... tanks

Comment: @Yusan: You just have to handle it in your navigation code, e.g., set a variable suppressing the message. That's if you really think the message is worthwhile; if your timeout mechanism works correctly, and you train people to log out, do you really need to nag? I mean, the user can also just stand up and walk away from the computer when logged in. That's a security concern too, and one that cannot be overcome except through user training (though there are some systems that use face recognition to lock a workstation if the person leaves; that's at an OS level).

Comment: I understand you are referring to but I need more explanation about the code is more detailed, thanks Mr.TJ Crowder

Comment: @Yusan: You drop that in the page. It's client-side code. In place of where I have the simple variable `loggedIn`, you'd have whatever test you need to have to see whether they're logged in. You might also have a variable saying you're navigating away from the page that you set any time navigation is done via a `click` handler or similar, so that you don't nag them in that case. That's pretty much it, very straightforward.