# How to disable browser minimize, maximize and close button on page load using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

On page load minimize , maximize and close button disable in any browser.

Comment: browser minimize , maximize and close button not work on click, If i try to close the window but not close window or browser.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can alter these settings on an existing window but you can affect these settings on a window that your code creates using the window.open() method.

See [Window.open() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Position_and_size_features). There are a *ton* of options you can set and mileage may vary per browser. i.e. it may not work in all cases. Also take note of the [usability issues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Usability_issues) of window.open() in the same article.

*example:*

```
window.open('http://www.google.com', 'WindowName', 'minimizable=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,titlebar=no,location=no')
```

It did not work exactly as expected in my tests with Chrome. e.g. turning off the location bar resulted in a read only location bar rather than removing it altogether. Other options were seemingly ignored. I think many A-Grade browsers are dropping support for this sort of thing due to potential for abuse from malicious sites.

Answer (score 0):

By default, max button of a window is enabled, but if you open as pop-up and pass some value as the window property in that case the max button might be disabled, please see below way to do this job:

Set window resizable property as either no or 0.

Format:
window.open("pageurl","PopupWindow","resizable=no"); //OR: resizable=0
Examples:

window.open("http://www.google.com","PopupWindow","resizable=0");
window.open("http://domainname.com/somepage.ext","PopupWindow","resizable=0");
window.open("http://domainname.com/somepage.ext","PopupWindow","resizable=no");

releated posts

http://forums.asp.net/t/1474854.aspx

[How To Disable Button Close On Browser For Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466193/how-to-disable-button-close-on-browser-for-web-application#6466215)